# Convert a query to join

Tags: sql, sybase

I need to make this query with joins but the result it is not the same, Can someone tell where is the fail?

this is the original query:

```
select count(*)
from 
CI_PRODUCTO,CI_PROD_CAT,CI_CLIENTE,CI_DIRECCIONES,CI_CANAL_ASOCIADO,
CI_CLIENTE_SGTO_CANAL,CI_PRODUCTO 
PROD_PADRE,CI_CONTRATO,CI_HISTORICO,CI_LOTES_FACTURACION,CI_CARACT_CLIENTE
where 
CI_PRODUCTO.swProdReleaseId=CI_PROD_CAT.swProdReleaseId and 
CI_PRODUCTO.swCustomerId=CI_CLIENTE.swCustomerId and
CI_CARACT_CLIENTE.swCustomerId=*CI_CLIENTE.swCustomerId and 
CI_CONTRATO.swAgreementId=CI_PRODUCTO.swAgreementId and
CI_LOTES_FACTURACION.swAgreementId=*CI_CONTRATO.swAgreementId and
CI_CLIENTE.swCustomerId=CI_CLIENTE_SGTO_CANAL.swCustomerId and 
CI_DIRECCIONES.swObjectId=CI_CLIENTE.swCustomerId and 
CI_PRODUCTO.swChnlPartnerId*=CI_CANAL_ASOCIADO.swChnlPartnerId and 
CI_PRODUCTO.swParentInstProdId*=PROD_PADRE.swInstProdId and
CI_HISTORICO.swObjectID=*CI_PRODUCTO.swInstProdId
```

This is the query I made and it's supposed to return the same that the query above:

```
select count(*)
from CI_PRODUCTO join CI_PROD_CAT on 
CI_PRODUCTO.swProdReleaseId=CI_PROD_CAT.swProdReleaseId
join CI_CLIENTE on CI_PRODUCTO.swCustomerId=CI_CLIENTE.swCustomerId 
join CI_CONTRATO on CI_CONTRATO.swAgreementId=CI_PRODUCTO.swAgreementId
left outer join CI_CANAL_ASOCIADO on 
CI_PRODUCTO.swChnlPartnerId=CI_CANAL_ASOCIADO.swChnlPartnerId
left outer join CI_PRODUCTO PROD_PADRE on 
CI_PRODUCTO.swParentInstProdId=PROD_PADRE.swInstProdId
left outer join CI_HISTORICO on CI_PRODUCTO.swInstProdId=CI_HISTORICO.swObjectID
left outer join CI_CARACT_CLIENTE on 
CI_CLIENTE.swCustomerId=CI_CARACT_CLIENTE.swCustomerId
join CI_CLIENTE_SGTO_CANAL on 
CI_CLIENTE.swCustomerId=CI_CLIENTE_SGTO_CANAL.swCustomerId
join CI_DIRECCIONES on CI_DIRECCIONES.swObjectId=CI_CLIENTE.swCustomerId
left outer join CI_LOTES_FACTURACION on 
CI_CONTRATO.swAgreementId=CI_LOTES_FACTURACION.swAgreementId
```

Comment: Hi noelia, can you explain what kind of "fail" you get?

Comment: I think you should start with just two tables in both queries.. and then slowly add one more table, until you identify where the issue is.

Comment: are both queries being run against the same database? if the answer is 'no' ... have you verified the data is the same in both databases?